# Rails Currency Formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app and I'm trying to figure out the best way of allowing users to change the currency format of a report. It's not something that would be tied to their country or location since they may have to send the report to people from other countries.

I initially only want support for these 3:
USD, GBP, and EUR

Also, there's no need for currency conversion. What's the best way to go about this in Rails?

Answer (score 10):

Check out the [`number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001684) helper.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using it, but it seems like it's the best solution right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than another drop down, I'd suggest a list of links that have different values with examples and then let the user click the one that matches what they are expecting.

To make things a little more user friendly you could also tie in with a [GeoIP](http://www.onrails.org/articles/2006/06/01/geoip-data) service to sort out what country they are from to set the default format.